# How to build a graph with certain fault tolerance

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to build a graph with $n$ vertices and $k \cdot n $ edges, I need to make sure that this graph is $2k$ connected, meaning that it cannot be disconnected by removing at most $2k-1$ vertices. I'm looking for an algorithm that given n,k outputs such a graph.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what kind of answer you are expecting/looking for.  Are you looking for an algorithm that given $n,k$ outputs such a graph?  Are you looking for an algorithm that given $n,k,G$ tests whether the graph $G$ has this property?  Do you have a fixed value of $n,k$ in mind and you just want an example of such a graph for that value of $n,k$?  Something else?  Is any algorithm OK or do you have running time requirements?

Comment: So, can you edit the question to clarify what you are asking and what sort of answer you are looking for?  It might also  help to tell us what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them.

Comment: **If** you are looking for a random generation, you must include a description of probability distribution for the possible graphs. [Otherwise...](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Do you know how to solve this for the special case $k=2$?  When $k$ is large enough (e.g., $k \gg \log n$), a random graph will be $2k$-connected with high probability, and I think you can test $2k$-connectivity using max-flow, so for large $k$, this should give you an efficient randomized algorithm for the problem.  I'm not sure how to handle small values of $k$.